# C#/EF column is of type uuid but expression is of type text

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, xunit

I was updating my .Net from Core 3.2 to 7.0 and my unit tests are going crazy.

I get this following error now

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
Npgsql.PostgresException : 42804: column "DefaultResourceId" is of type uuid but expression is of type text
```

I tracked it through this

Class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public string DefaultResourceId { get; set; }
}
```

Snapshot

```
b.Property<string>("DefaultResourceId")
    .HasColumnType("text");
```

Postgres

```
DefaultResourceId | Text | Default | Not Null []
```

Code resulting in error

```
public TContext DbContext => Factory.Server.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<TContext>();
var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid()
            };

await DbContext.AddAsync(user);
await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The code is working smoothly otherwise, so i am not sure where to begin. Any ideas?

- I ran the tests
- everything working as expected but this error in the test (other tests that don't use this ApplicationUser are working fine).
- Not sure where this "uuid" stuff is coming from or where it could be.
- N.B. This was a Guid but was changed a year ago and wasn't a problem ever since the migration to 7.0

Answer (score 0):

UUID is another term for GUID. (Universal Unique ID vs. Global Unique ID)

The exception is telling you that while EF is configured to expect a string, the Database your test is talking to has the column still as a GUID/UUID.

This means that whatever database your tests are talking to still has the column type as a PostreSQL UUID type rather than a Varchar/Text column. Often this issue can come up when you have multiple databases and update one but connection strings used by tests point at an older schema that wasn't updated. (when running schema-first rather than code-first) That or there was an issue where migrations weren't run against the test database.

Check the connection string you think the test is running against, or use a breakpoint in the test to inspect the DbContext.Database.ConnectionString to verify if it's actually pointing at where you think it is pointing.

Comment: yes, thank you. Not sure what was happening but it was connecting to the correct server but a non-existing database. It didn't give me an error that the db is missing just those random thing. How or why I don't know.

Comment: If your data context is set up to use migrations it may be that there are migrations present that create the UUID version of the field, but then when that was changed to a string they stopped creating/using migrations. If the DbContext was pointed at a non-existing Database, none of your tests would have been successful, but if Migrations were activated it may have created the DB, just in an out of date schema.